# How do I increment a score with an inconsistent variable?

Tags: java, increment

Every time I run my code score always gets replaced by sides and not incremented like it's supposed too. Keep in mind the assignment has to be object oriented hence all the method calls. the code is a variation of the game idle dice.
Here is all the relevant code, I've tried everything I can think of, I'm 95% sure the problem is in my setScore method.

```
 public void rollDice()
    {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 6;
        mult = 1;
        sides = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
        System.out.println("You rolled a " + sides);
        sides = sides * mult;
        System.out.println("You earned " + sides + " points");
    }

public void addScore()
{
    McMurchyScore give = new McMurchyScore();
    give.setScore(sides);
}

public void setScore(double sides)
{
    score = score + sides;
    
    System.out.println("You now have a total " + score + " points");
}
```

Comment: This post should be tagged with Java not Javascript.

Comment: `addScore` probably shouldn't create a new object each time. Assuming all of this code is *inside* of the `McMurchScore` class, it should probably just be `setScore(sides)` (or `this.setScore(sides)`, if you wish to be explicit) and nothing else. Of course, there's still some suboptimal structure in that code, but it should at least work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call addScore(), it creates a new McMurchyScore object (which I assume starts with 0 score), so you'll need to keep using the same McMurchy score if you want them to keep adding to the same one.